# Server side validation using code inginter

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, post, insert

I am new to the codeinginter. It is very different from my past coding experience, what I currently would like to do is post data to server and checking. Since the input box is dynamic generate , it make my adding function very messy.

First for each data it must has 1 title and 1 content, and randomly number (or none) a link group (linktext and link ) E.g. LinkText1 , Link1 , LinkText2, Link2....and so on.

I would like to do this in more elegant way.

What I now doing is have 2 method in models , 1 for  title and  content , after interst it, return last id , base on this id append all the others link group.

```
public function add()
{
    //if save button was clicked, get the data sent via post
    if ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') === 'POST')
    {
        //form validation
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', '消息標題', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('content', '消息內容', 'required');
        foreach ($this->input->post() as $key => $value) {
            if (strstr($key,"linkText") !== False) {
                $this->form_validation->set_rules($key, '連結標題', 'required');
            }
            else if (strstr($key,"link") !== False) {
                 $this->form_validation->set_rules($key, '連結地址', 'required');
            }
        }
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="alert alert-error"><a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a><strong>', '</strong></div>');

        //if the form has passed through the validation
        if ($this->form_validation->run())
        {
            $data_to_store = array(
                'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
                'content' => $this->input->post('content')
            );

            //if the insert has returned true then we show the flash message
            $lastID = $this->news_model->store_news($data_to_store);

            if($lastID !== False){
                foreach ($this->input->post() as $key => $value) {
                    if (strstr($key,"linkText") !== False) {
                        $linkText = $key;
                    }else if (strstr($key,"link") !== False) {
                        $link = $key;
                    }

                    if (isset($linkText) && isset($link)) {
                        $data_to_store = array(
                        'title' => $this->input->post($linkText),
                        'url' => $this->input->post($link),
                        'news_id' => $lastID
                        );

                        if($this->news_model->store_news_link($data_to_store)){
                            $data['flash_message'] = TRUE;
                        } else {
                            $data['flash_message'] = FALSE; 
                        }
                    }
                }
            }else{
                $data['flash_message'] = FALSE; 
            }
        }else{
                $data['flash_message'] = FALSE; 
        }
    }   
    //load the view
    $data['main_content'] = 'admin/news/add';
    $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
}
```

it loop 2 times, and many repeated code, are there more elegant way to implement this? Thanks for helping.

Comment: thanks for remind. updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove

```
if ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') === 'POST')
```

because

```
$this->form_validation->run()
```

is taking care of it.

Also please get rid of the many

```
$data['flash_message'] = FALSE;
```

Just put that line at the start of your function and then change it to true when you need it. It doesn't make sense to copy paste that all over your code.

I am not sure I understand the question, but I think you are looking for input arrays like

```
<input name="myarray[]" ... />
```

CodeIgniter can validate those, see [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#arraysasfields)